# Adding XML nodes into an existing XML config file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I currently have an XML file that contains a node like this (in the middle of the XML file):

```
<StationsSection>
    <Stations />
</StationsSection>
```

I need to append to it so it becomes this:

```
<StationsSection>
    <Stations>
        <add Comment="I'm here!" DestinationFolderPath="C:\" FtpHostname="ftp://upload.domain.com/" FtpFolderPath="myFolder/" FtpUsername="555" FtpPassword="secret!!!" FtpTimeoutInSeconds="20" />
        <add Comment="I'm here!" DestinationFolderPath="C:\" FtpHostname="ftp://upload.domain.com/" FtpFolderPath="myFolder/" FtpUsername="555" FtpPassword="secret!!!" FtpTimeoutInSeconds="20" />
    </Stations>
</StationsSection>
```

That data ("Comment", "DestinationFolderPath", etc.) is currently stored in a generic list of a custom object - called "updatedStations". When I try to add them like this:

```
foreach (var station in updatedStations)
{
    XElement updatedStation = new XElement("add", elementToAdd); // "elementToAdd" has a value
    xml.Add(updatedStation); // "xml" is an XDocument
}
```

...that "updatedStation" variable has this value:

```
<add>Comment="I'M HERE!" DestinationFolderPath="C:\" FtpHostname="myFolder/" FtpFolderPath="ftp://upload.domain.com/" FtpUsername="555" FtpPassword="secret!!!" FtpTimeoutInSeconds="20"</add>
```

When it tries this line:

```
xml.Add(updatedStation);
```

I get this exception:

> This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.

How can I get this to work?... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string operations( like `updatedStation` ). Below is an example with Linq2Xml + XPath (assuming you can get the parts of `updatedStation`)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var st = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//StationsSection/Stations");
st.Add(new XElement(
            "add", 
            new XAttribute("Comment","I'm here"),
            new XAttribute("DestinationFolderPath","C:\\")  )
       );
```

PS: Don't forget to include namespaces

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```